# Create file which has errors

Tags: c, file

My question is what should I do with file so that I get errors while fwrite (other arguments in fwrite is correct). What if file will be with set read only attribute?

```
FILE *pFile = NULL;

pFile = fopen(path, "wb");
if (!pFile) {
return RET_FILE_OPEN_ERROR;
}
//ba is OK
result = fwrite(ba->buf, sizeof(uint8_t), ba->len, pFile);
if (result != ba->len) {
fclose(pFile);
return RET_FILE_WRITE_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Are you *trying* to generate errors, or asking how to handle errors that occur?

Comment: I think she wants to make `fwrite` fail for testing purposes. Setting the file to read only will fail in `fopen`, so that won't work.

Comment: Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with all of required declaretions of structures and variables?

Comment: If @rustyx 's undestanding of the purpose of your question is correct then you can `fopen` file on, for example, 1) shared location, 2) - usb/floppy drive, then 1) close that share or 2) remove usb/floppy drive from computer  and then perform your `fwrite'

Answer (score 1):

If you want just an error (that is, you don't care which one), the simplest one to get (on Linux) is `EFBIG`. Use `setrlimit(RLIMIT_FSIZE, ...)` to limit the max size of the file. Don't forget to catch `SIGXFZ` signal.

On Windows you may play with disk quotas.

Another way is to create a really small loopback device (or VHD on Windows), and enjoy a "No space left on device" error.